# Evaluate $\int{ \boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{x} \exp^{-\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{x}} \, d\boldsymbol{x}}$

Tags: integration

How can one proceed to evaluate the integral

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{ \boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{x} \exp^{-\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{x}} \, d\boldsymbol{x}}$

This case of $\boldsymbol{x}$ being vector valued is throwing me off. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: To begin with: do you understand how it would look like in coordinates?

Comment: You probably meant $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}$ not $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$. In which case the solution is to find the closed-form of $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} e^{-a\|x\|^2}d^n x$ and differentiate wrt $a$